# REST: Processing error in long running operation, how to inform clients?

Tags: rest, api, jersey

I am developing a webservice that alllows users to request validation reports. Report generation might take up to 20 hours per report. When a new validation request is posted, I return a 202 Accepted answer with Location set to a processing queue (e.g.`/queue/5`) When the queue resource is polled some processing information is provided:

`<queueResponse>
    <status>QUEUED</status>
    <queuePosition>1</queuePosition>
</queueResponse>`

Once processing completes successfully and the queue is polled, a 303 see other will redirect to the created resource (at `/reports/5` e.g.).

However if a processing error occurs on server, i simply return my queueResponse without redirect and status set to `<status>ERROR</status>`.

Is this the best way to comunicate a processing error to the client? Or should instead simply a 500 Internal Server Error returned when polling the queue for a failed validation task?.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is best. A 500 error for the queued process information would indicate that the request for that resource had failed, not the process it was reporting on.

postscript: If your API is still being defined, I would suggest FAILED instead of ERROR, as it sounds more permanent. Errors are potentially recoverable situations, failures are not.